# Working with generated classes and Jackson to read stream of JSON data to objects

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have generated classes from a Swagger definition. There are 4 different classes with one field in common `op` (there is no class hierarchy, the field is replicated in each class).

I want to deserialise a stream of JSON data into one of the 4 different classes depending on the value of the `op` field.

For example:

```
{"op": "typeA", ...} -> generates TypeA
{"op": "typeB", ...} -> generates TypeB
```

I want to use Jackson for this. The problem Im having is that all examples I find assumes that you are able to modify the original classes so that you can make a class hierarchy to solve the problem. However my question is how can I solve this without having to modify the original classes?

The original example assumes a hierarchy and is done like this:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
        property = "op",
        visible = true)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ConnectionMessage.class, name = "connection"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = StatusMessage.class, name = "status"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = MarketChangeMessage.class, name = "mcm"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = OrderChangeMessage.class, name = "ocm"),
})
public interface MixInResponseMessage {

}
```

Comment: Not completely the answer, as this assumes a hierachy - but you should still be able to take the idea (if its possible) by using Mixins. Here's an example that of using a mixin to target a parent abstract class. https://github.com/Flaw101/springbootmixin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with a custom deserializer with a switch - case statement to parse the correct type according to the value of "op" field:

```
class OpDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer {
    private final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public Object deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {
        final JsonNode node = jsonParser.readValueAsTree();
        final String op = node.get("op").asText();
        switch (op) {
            case "typeA": return mapper.treeToValue(node, TypeA.class);
            case "typeB": return mapper.treeToValue(node, TypeB.class);
            default: return mapper.treeToValue(node, Object.class);
        }
    }
}
```

Note how an `ObjectMapper` field is used to convert a `TreeNode` to an object of required type.

This doesn't require `TypeA`, `TypeB` etc to have any other common parent except `Object`.

It'll be necessary to specify this deserializer as used for each JSON element with an `"op"` field. I tested by parsing this class:

```
class Ops {
    @JsonDeserialize(contentUsing = OpDeserializer.class)
    Object[] ops;
}
```